# How do i format script inside in APIMocker?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i want to check a conditions based  on a flag my parameter or id in service url and based on flag or id or query to checking if condition or checking the flag using any dynamic javascript injection inside config.json file from apimocker.
 requirement is that based on flag i need to change the switch id as same as mockfile path from json to xml folder.

example:

```
"var/:id": {
  "mockFile": "xml/queen.xml",
  "verbs": ["all"],
  "switch": "id"
}
```

if(flag)
   //var name should  change as test.

is possible ? i hope that it is not possible to do script or conditions inside ? but..any possiblities to archieve it.

Thanks for your help

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but JSON is just a string with a particular syntax, you cannot put any logic into it. (Elaborate: where is this flag stored? What manipulates the json depending on it?)

Comment: hi doldt,      thanks for ur inputs and i need to set flag based on content type is equal to json or xml as query parametre to load corresponding response using apimocker or some other custom script in nodejs. i couldnt find the solution..